# How to show response after executing query with php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

Hello i managed to execute my query using php/pdo and with the help of jQuery and everything going fine expect i don't know how to show response when the query is executing.

form code

```
<form id="example" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="amount" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="description" /><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" onClick="$.post('add.php', $('form#example').serialize())">
</form>
```

add.php

```
$amount         = $_POST['amount'];
$description    = $_POST['description'];
$password       = $_POST['password'];

$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO money (amount, description, password) VALUES (:amount, :description, :password)");
$q->execute(array(':amount' => $amount, ':description' => $description, ':password' => $password));
```

The query going fine i want to know how can i show a success message on the main page thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you return the data in json?

Comment: @blo i didn't show the result yet but i need response for the success the code showed here is all i have no more codes in my page

Comment: You to echo in your php file to return that data to the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Use the success callback function from the post method and output whatevery message you like.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add"
   onClick="$.post('add.php', $('form#example').serialize(), function() { $(body).append($('<div />').text('success'); })">
```

Comment: It will probably be better and more readable to put that inside a script tag and not like that

Comment: This gave me strange result in query i dont know how anyway iam trying to execute alert script from the php page after the success of the query i don't know if this right to do this or no.